# Pymongo - checking for combinations in a collection? MongoDB

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo, querying

I have a question: Suppose I have a particular field whose value is ObjectId(x) for many x, and said x corresponds to a particular userId in a different collection. I need to find patterns in my database. How can I query for whether two x's show up multiple times in documents? In other words,

```
{
   'field' : [ObjectId(x),ObjectId(y)]
}
```

or

```
{
   'field' : [ObjectId(a), ObjectId(b)]
}
```

or

```
{
   'field' : [ObjectId(car), ObjectId(mouse)]
}
```

How can I query for whether a and b repeat in different documents or car and mouse or x and y. In other words how can I query for general patterns in the collection without actually using the Id? I apologize if I'm not being too specific. Let me know if you have questions. Thanks all!

Comment: When you say patterns you wan't to find Correlation between x and z and sort by it? do you have the "patterns" you want well defined?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I want to narrow down the population by querying ONLY for the documents that share this repeated trait for two or more documents. for example, document 1 could be [object(mouse), object(tree), .... , object(blah)] and document 2 could be [object(blah), ..., object(tree), object(mouse)] In this case, since mouse and tree show up in two different documents, they are candidates for this query. My goal is to ONLY show the documents that posses this trait.